# почему исчезает при изменении экрана выпадающий список?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

http://ok.novikspecteh.dp.ua/m/
остается только надпись "Per Page"
если уменьшать без перезагрузки страницы то все ок, а если перезагрузить на уменьшенном экране то сразу пропадает, даже не просто уменьшить а просто нажать просмотреть в браузере и перезагрузить пропадет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Параметры надо куда-нибудь сохранять (cookie, сессия, get-параметры) при их изменении. А при загрузке страницы проверять их на существование и использовать.

Comment: проверил с 6сти устройств ..все выпадашки работают и отображаются, вопрос исправьте с пояснениями что пропадает и на каком устройстве

Comment: @MaximLensky пропадает выпадающий список на хромиум и на айфоне